# How to set dates outwidth a specific time period to NA in R

Tags: r, date

I have a large dataframe (x) in which one of my columns (Visit_Date) contains a number of dates.

Unfortunately, some data in this column refers to DoB and not Visit_Date. For example, the dates in this column should only from 01/01/2015 to 01/03/2017, but I have dates such as 16/09/1964.

My question is, how can I set all dates prior to 01/01/2015 to NA?

Comment: `x$Visit_Date[x$Visit_Date<as.Date("2015-01-01")] <- NA`

Answer (score 0):

Here is my simple solution.

```
library(lubridate)

x <- data.frame(
  value = 1:5,
  Visit_Date = c("01/01/2015","21/02/2015",
                 "01/03/2015","16/09/1964",
                 "01/09/2015")
 )

x$Visit_Date <- dmy(x$Visit_Date)

index <- x$Visit_Date < dmy("01/01/2015")
x[index,"Visit_Date"] <- NA
x

#   value Visit_Date
# 1     1 2015-01-01
# 2     2 2015-02-21
# 3     3 2015-03-01
# 4     4       <NA>
# 5     5 2015-09-01
```